# How to input two integers in a same line?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, map-function

This a simple line of code used to input 2 integers in the same line.
**A, B = map(int, input().split())**
Please tell me how it's working using the map function?

Comment: There are [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp) for that kind of question. Break it down into what does `input().split()` return and what does `A, B = map(int, ["2", "3"])` do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, the `input()` method will always return a string. Your provided code snippet tries to split that input, and the `split()` function defaults to splitting on a space character.

The `map()` function takes a function (in this case, the `int` function), and applies that function to each part of the enumerable returned by the `split()` function.

So, if you were to write `a, b = map(int, input().split(" "))`, and then the user entered `123 456`, you would have `a == 123` and `b == 456`.

Let's take this as an example: `a, b = map(int, input().split())`

This is what's going to happen:

1. The `input()` function gets executed, and let's say that the user enters `123 456`
2. This gets interpreted as `"123 456"`, and then gets passed into the split function, like this: `"123 456".split()` which returns a list that looks like this: `["123", "456"]`.
3. Now you can sort of imagine that the code looks like this: `map(int, ["123", "456"])`, which might be a bit easier to reason about.
4. What's going to happen now is that the `map` function will take its first argument (the `int` function), and apply that to each element of the `["123", 456"]` list (that is, `"123"` and `"456"`).
5. The `map()` function returns an enumerable, which you in this case can think of as looking like the result of `[int("123"), int("456")]`, which results in `[123, 456]`
6. The unpacking of the assignment happens. You can think of that like this: `a, b = [123, 456]`